# Symfony Loading data by association?

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

Update

This is what my user table looks like what I var_dump the data,

```
private 'id' => int 2
private 'username' => string 'admin' (length=5)
private 'password' => string '$..........' (length=60)
private 'firstname' => string 'test1' (length=5)
private 'surname' => string 'test2' (length=5)
private 'email' => string 'test@test.com' (length=13)
private 'accessLevelsId' => int 1
```

And set in my AccessLevel Table are the following,

```
id  level       leveltitle 
1   ROLE_ADMIN  Admin
2   ROLE_USER   User
```

So when I look up my user, 'accesslevel_id' will just go away a set my user to the right role. I just dont know how to do that?

---

Ok I am very new to the world of Symfony, but I have used CakePHP quite a lot, so I have a good understand of MVC. However when you bake in CakePHP, it goes away and maps all the associated IDs with there primary key.

Symfony dose not seem to do that, or more Doctrine dose not seem to do more than set basic getters & setters.

So I am trying to build a users login. So far, it will work so load as I set the 'ROLE' in my `getRoles()` to return the right role, e.g. admin / user.

But I have a `access_levels_id` in my users table, which I want it to load the ROLE in from. But I have been all over the Symfony site and can not figure out how to do this.

```
/**
 * @var integer
 *
 *  @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="AccessLevels")
 *  @ORM\Column(name="access_levels_id", type="integer", nullable=false)
 *  @ORM\JoinColumn(name="access_levels_id", referencedColumnName="id")
 */
private $accessLevelsId;
```

This is currently what I have in my users entity, I have added, the `ManyToOne` and `JoinColumn` to this ID. I also add this to my AccessLevels entity

```
/**
* @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Users", mappedBy="accesslevels")
*/
public $users;

public function __contruct() {
    $this->users = new ArrayCollection();
}
```

I have added all the needed 'use' statements in both entities, or at lest I think I have.

Once I log the user in, with a role set the 'admin' I do a `var_dump` on the 'user' entity. But this just shows the `private 'accessLevelsId' => int 1` and not the 'ROLE' this is meant to go and fetch (on login).

So I thought (please let me know if this is just wrong) that I should make a new function, in my users entity, so I can fetch the data I need, then return that data to my `getRole() function`.

```
public function getAccessRole() {
    $GetUsersAccessID = $this->getAccessLevelsId();

    $TestMe = new AccessLevels();

   // $TestMe2 = $TestMe->find(1);

    var_dump( $GetUsersAccessID );
    var_dump( $TestMe );
    //var_dump( $TestMe2 );
}
```

So `$GetUsersAccessID`  returns the right data, my Access Level ID for that user, but I can not seem to figure out how to fetch that data from a entity inside my users entity. This also seems wrong to me? Not sure if this is best practice.

Thanks,

Comment: After reading this I'm totally confused about what you're trying to archieve. Are you trying to get the roles, are you trying to get the `AccessRoles`? Or does your implementation `getAccessRole` seems wrong to you? I think you have to take a look at interface `Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserInterface` for more info about the roles. Does your user implement that interface?

Comment: no it dose not right now. Ok so on a basic level, I have a table, which holds my roles, ROLE_ADMIN, ROLE_USER. This table's, 'access_level', ID, is what my 'users' table points to.  So that when the user logs in, that data is fetch, and my users rights (admin or user) are by whatever access_level ID that user points to. Sorry I am not very good at explain myself sometimes, dose that make it clear what I want?

Comment: There is no question or problem in your explanation. If the data is loaded properly, what is your problem exactly then? If you want to match the roles with your own implementation, you should do that in your own implementation of the user.

Comment: I have a look at UserInteface but what I want to do is very simply get the accesslevel name not its ID. So when I var_dump my user, I can get what role that has been assign to that user

Comment: I have update my question with a bit more details, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Via the `UserInterface`, your `User` obtains the roles relation. It is a `ManyToMany` relationship. In other words, you do not need to instantiate it yourself, but implement the interface and update your database.

More info about the interface and it's consequences can be found on: http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/security/entity_provider.html

Comment: Yeah I have been all over that page, however it dose not explain how to config getRoles from the database

Comment: Yes it does: `$ php app/console doctrine:schema:update --force`

Comment: I am sorry but I just dont see how that maps my IDs? This is what I get back when I run it, 'Nothing to update - your database is already in sync with the current entity metadata.' - There is nothing in there about loading Roles from another table via a ID field on the users table, I would have thought that this is common.